# Why do some 8051 program ends with the code "LOOP: SJMP LOOP"

Tags: assembly, 8051

Almost all the simple 8051 programs I have seen so far ends with the code 
`LOOP: SJMP LOOP`.

From my understanding I think the above instruction creates an infinite loop by calling the same instruction again and again. But what is the purpose of having infinite loop at the end of a program and if it keeps running again and again then when does the program gets terminated.

Comment: So that the program doesn't continue executing random/semi-random data after the last instruction. The CPU sees it all as data and will gladly try to execute whatever is in memory thus causing undefined behavior. Putting processor in a loop like that prevents the CPU wandering aimlessly through whatever remains in memory.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How else do you "terminate" or end a bare metal program?  There generally is no halt or other command, the processor doesnt stop.  The safest/cleanest is to have it infinite loop (as opposed to just wandering through memory trying to execute what it finds).

so for simple educational processor/microcontroller programs, programs that "end", you would want to end them in an infinite loop if the processor doesnt have a halt.  Most mcus never halt they run whatever forever (they might go to sleep in a low power state, but then wake up when you press a button on the remote or whatever).